# MacBook Pro gets hot and slow when using Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, macbook, overheating, fan, macbook-pro

I recently bought a MacBook pro 2012. 
I have also installed Ubuntu 18.04 but it is overheating when I'm using ubuntu.
I have installed **macfanctld** and **mbpfan** and I have set the min fan speed to 6000
When I type **sensors** in the terminal, I see the fan speed is **0 rpm** and the MacBook is still getting very hot. I also checked the the list daemons running and the above packages are in the list. The computer becomes super slow after about 30 minutes of usage.

 can some one help me fix this problem? If I am on macOS, the computer does not get hot

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +94.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:        +94.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:        +94.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

BAT0-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.2°C  

applesmc-isa-0300
Adapter: ISA adapter
Exhaust  :      0 RPM  (min = 6000 RPM, max = 6200 RPM)
TA0P:         +55.8°C  
TB0T:         +41.0°C  
TB1T:         +41.0°C  
TB2T:         +39.5°C  
TC0E:         +96.2°C  
TC0F:         +96.8°C  
TC0J:          +0.5°C  
TC0P:         +85.2°C  
TC1C:         +93.0°C  
TC2C:         +94.0°C  
TCGC:         +90.0°C  
TCSA:         +92.0°C  
TCTD:          -0.2°C  
TCXC:         +94.0°C  
TG1D:         +96.8°C  
TM0P:         +53.0°C  
TM0S:         +78.2°C  
TPCD:         +91.0°C  
Th1H:         +70.8°C  
Ts0P:         +37.5°C  
Ts0S:         +58.5°C
```

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04, I have updated the tags

Comment: Can you add the output of `mbpfan -v -f`?  This should log the temperatures and fan speeds to stdout.

Comment: Also, please only use `mbpfan` or `macfanctld`, not both.  Installing both will cause the two daemons to conflict with each other.

Comment: What is the GPU there?

Comment: It was an issue with my fan. it was blocked by a small plastic. I removed the plastic and it started working. Thanks for your concern.